# Appending bytes

Tags: java, android

i am developing an Android application and I am having some issues with adding bytes to compose a data packet. I have created a method to get the MAC Address of the client and the return value is a string (MACAdd).

```
private String getMACAddress() {
    WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
    MACAdd= info.getMacAddress();
    return MACAdd;
}
```

I have declared MACAddrs as a static String and have done the following assignment in createPackect() method. 
    MACAddrs = getMACAddress();
    byte [] MACAddres = MACAddrs.getBytes();

In the same createPacket() method, I have declared following data as well.

```
    byte Node = (byte)0x3039;
    byte Cost = (byte)0x1;
    byte MaxMsgSize = (byte) 0x100000;
    byte KeepAlivePiriod = (byte)0x2710;
    byte NetworkID = (byte)0x1;
```

I need to add these bytes into a single array to compose the data packet.

```
byte[] BroadcastPacket = new byte[Node + Cost + SerialNumber + MaxMsgSize + KeepAlivePiriod +  NetworkID  + MACAddres + IPAddress];
```

as I am adding two different byte types, I am having a error. Please advise me how to solve this issue......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convenience method to concatenate byte arrays might help:

```
byte[] concatArrays(byte[] ... arrays) {
    int totalLength = 0;
    for (byte[] arr : arrays) {
        totalLength += arr.length;
    }
    byte[] result = new byte[totalLength];
    int start = 0;
    for (byte[] arr : arrays) {
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, result, start, arr.length);
        start += arr.length;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using this, you could create `byte[] BroadcastPacket` like this:

```
byte[] BroadcastPacket = concatArrays(
    new byte[Node + Cost + SerialNumber + MaxMsgSize + KeepAlivePiriod +  NetworkID],
    MACAddrs.getBytes(),
    IPAddrs.getBytes()
);
```

Btw, you should use `camelCase` for variable names.

And you don't need to cast such values to `byte`:

> ```
> byte cost = (byte) 0x1;
> ```

This works just as well:

```
byte cost = 0x1;
```

If the value you're trying to assign to a `byte` doesn't actually fit into a byte,
casting to byte you are losing precision, for example here:

> ```
> byte b3 = (byte) 0x100000;
> ```

If you don't mind the precision loss by design, that's fine, otherwise this can be a nasty bug.